# How to use jquery-ui themes to style buttons that needs 2 images

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a button (created by a designer), that cannot be represented by background + border radius (it has a 3D-like effect, so the "radius" should be an image as well.

It is clear from tutorials [like this one](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html) how to make such buttons. However, the jquery-ui seems to have only these (relevant) classes:

- `.ui-state-default` that holds the background image for the button and other components
- `.ui-button` - that defines button-only properties.

But the code is only one `<input`, so it can't have the two images, Is there a way to have `$("..").button()` use both images? I guess I can have some spans inside `<button>`, but having that everywhere is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

there are several states associated with buttons and all widgets:

The following are the relevant classes and their relation to the button widget:

- `ui-state-default`

  - The button properties as it appears on the page
- `ui-state-active`

  - The button properties as it is being clicked
- `ui-state-hover`

  - The button properties as it is hovered

In the theme's css sheet there are each of these settings within the button settings that generally have a color or image set from the themeroller.

You could override the default properties to use your own images if you wanted either through another stylesheet or rewrite the one from themeroller.

You can also easily set the themeroller settings to give you a 3D look by setting the colors and opacities.  If you need this only for buttons and not for your entire page, use the CSS scope feature.

[Themeroller is here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

[Themeroller example with similar button to your example](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#ffDefault=Verdana%2CArial%2Csans-serif&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=100px&bgColorHeader=cccccc&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=75&borderColorHeader=aaaaaa&fcHeader=222222&iconColorHeader=222222&bgColorContent=ffffff&bgTextureContent=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityContent=75&borderColorContent=aaaaaa&fcContent=222222&iconColorContent=222222&bgColorDefault=ebebeb&bgTextureDefault=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=100&borderColorDefault=999999&fcDefault=555555&iconColorDefault=888888&bgColorHover=ebebeb&bgTextureHover=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityHover=100&borderColorHover=999999&fcHover=212121&iconColorHover=454545&bgColorActive=c2c2c2&bgTextureActive=06_inset_hard.png&bgImgOpacityActive=80&borderColorActive=999999&fcActive=212121&iconColorActive=454545&bgColorHighlight=fbf9ee&bgTextureHighlight=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=55&borderColorHighlight=fcefa1&fcHighlight=363636&iconColorHighlight=2e83ff&bgColorError=fef1ec&bgTextureError=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityError=95&borderColorError=cd0a0a&fcError=cd0a0a&iconColorError=cd0a0a&bgColorOverlay=aaaaaa&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=0&opacityOverlay=30&bgColorShadow=aaaaaa&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=0&opacityShadow=30&thicknessShadow=8px&offsetTopShadow=-8px&offsetLeftShadow=-8px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px)

Comment: I know about the three states, but that doesn't help with forming the button (I just have to form it in 3 different ways). Also - how do I achieve the 3d look by "colors and opacities"?

Comment: Ok, sorry I misunderstood what you were asking at first.  Your best bet would likely be to add the spans as in that tutorial.  As you said, that would be cumbersome to do everywhere. I think you may be stuck with editing some source code here if you go with jQuery UI.  You may be able to extend the button widget into your own widget and extend the functionality to maintain the spans as well...

Comment: As far as the themeroller goes, you can create a very similar button as in that tutorial using the colors of the button states and the opacities of the overlay effects. Setting the border radius to a huge number will make it look like that capsule style on the example page

Comment: I think I will implement my `$("#foo").styledButton()` function

Comment: Ok, just as an example, I put a link to a button to the themeroller with a button example that looks like the example you posted...granted everything else looks like crap, but that is what css scopes could be used for

Comment: so the link you posted is 2d? if so, that is fine, and that is what i was going by.  Semantically, it has a 3d feel as it has a height and width, and the gradients give it a depth look.  You may have images that look more pronounced in the depth areas making it "more 3D" if you will.  If you want those images, you need to hack at the css, write an extension to the button widget, or write your own plugin altogether